# Simple HTML DOM Parser not same as Chrome Source Viewer?

Tags: php

Trying to get code from this page [xem-phim-sat-pha-lang-kill-zone](http://phimhay77.com/xem-phim-sat-pha-lang-kill-zone-33797)

if press F12 on Chrome and Press Ctrl+F to find Object Tags, you will see Object tag with flashvar and some param tags.
but i use Simple_html_dom.php to parsing, it cannot show that Object tags...

```
$html2=file_get_html('http://phimhay77.com/xem-phim-sat-pha-lang-kill-zone-33797');
$hihi=$html2->find('object',0);
echo htmlentities($hihi);
```

Comment: isn't it added dynamically with javascript?

Comment: what i must do if it is added by javascript.

Comment: you can't see it then with a simple get request, you need to execute the javascript of the page from within a browser or a headless browser at least...

Answer (score 1):

If you press Ctrl-F in Chrome then you see the DOM: which is the DOM from the original source HTML, plus modifications cause by any JavaScript which has run.

My guess is that the `<object>` which you see was created by JavaScript, and that the `<object>`does not exist in the original source HTML (I don't see an `<object>` in the HTML when I do "view page source"); and I guess that file_get_html is parsing the HTML without/before any modifications made to the DOM by JavaScript.

I suspect that the `<object>` which you're seeing is from the 'jwplayer' video player component (see [this hyperlink](http://www.jwplayer.com/) and [this hyperlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jwplayer) for further details), which uses inserts `<object>` into the DOM if it's run in a browser which supports the Adobe Flash player.

---

> So How can I parsing Value of "Proxy.link" from this script?

It's here in the HTML source code:

```
<div id="media" >
    <div id="mediaplayer"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("mediaplayer").setup({
    "flashplayer": "http://player.xixam.com/player.swf",
    "width": "100%",
    "height": "100%",
    "proxy.link": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a65tyLkqR8U",
    "repeat": "list",
    "autostart": "true",
"skin":"http://coiphim.vn/public/js/player_5/nacht/nacht.xml",
"controlbar":"bottom",
    "plugins": "captions,timeslidertooltipplugin-2,fbit-1,http://player.xixam.com/plugins4/proxy.swf",
    "captions.file": "http://phimhay77.com/player/alophim.srt",
    "captions.color": "#FFCC00",
    "captions.fontFamily": "Arian,sans-serif",
    "captions.fontSize": "18",
"logo.file":       "http://phimhay77.com/player/logo.png",
    "logo.position":       "top-left",
    "logo.margin":       "5",
    "logo.over":       "1",
    "logo.out":       "1",
    "logo.hide":       "false",
    events: {
            onComplete: function autonext() {
     Phim3s.Watch.autoNextExecute();
}

        }
    });
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: So How can I parsing Value of "Proxy.link" from this script?

http://jsbin.com/iVUXeNov/1/